# Alternative to sympy simplfiy_logic for large logical expressions?

Tags: python, sympy

```
sympy.logic.boolalg.simplify_logic(expr, form=None, deep=True, force=False)
```

I have been trying sympy's logic function `simplify_logic` with `force=True` to evaluate a large equation in the form of `eqn=(A&B|C)&(A|D)|(A|T&F)...`

I would also like to set it to disjunctive normal form (dnf) or SOP form which is what the function does but it takes exponentially more time as I add more variables to the equation I need to evaluate. Does anyone know better functions for these type of problems?

Comment: There is no sub-exponential time algorithm for DNF (or CNF) in general (without introducing dummy variables) because the output can have size exponential in the size of the input (consider putting `A&B|C&D|E&F|…` into CNF).